# How to make SWTableViewCell swipe more sticky

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I've implemented the `SWTableViewCell` code in order to allow side swipes to reveal more UI, such as buttons.

Which is working fine, except that the `UIScrollview` it subclasses is really just too touchy, flicking back and forth like a manic game of ping pong.

I went to make changes to the class, but realised `UIScrollView` didn't seem to give me the ability to say change the way the scrolling animations work in the way I wanted.

Leaving me thinking that I either need to create my own version of the a Swipe cell, with a pan gesture and a overlay view, instead of a scrollview or find someone who has already solved this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check it out sample: https://github.com/runmad/RMSwipeTableViewCell

May be it will helpful to you, Sir

:)

Comment: Thanks, I used your code to update SWTableViewCell to work in a similar fashion. Next time I think I'll just use RMSwipeTableViewCell. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will give you the effect you desire, but you can make it less "jumpy" by altering the decelerationRate.  Try:

```
someScrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
```

If that's the right idea, you can jump-to-definition in Xcode, and checkout the float value, then try your own.